# ScriptProcessorNode - prevent jittering?

Tags: web-audio-api, scriptprocessor

I'm using a `ScriptProcessorNode` in order to record audio from a `MediaStream`/`MediaStreamNode`. Any time a UI operation blocks the main thread a little bit (like drawing on a canvas), the audio result is jittery at those specific moments.

[It seems like `AudioWorker` is eventually going to be implemented](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/113), which I think would solve my problem, but as of now, what is the solution?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MediaRecorder API to record rather than ScriptProcessor, is my only advice.

Comment: I've tried the MediaRecordier API before, but it didn't work in Chrome, since the MediaRecorder API can only record `ogg` files and `AudioContext.decodeAudioData` can't decode `ogg` files in Chrome.

Comment: Have you checked in Canary?  I think that's being fixed.

Comment: I think MediaRecorder records in opus, not ogg.  `decodeAudioData` supports ogg.  And I think decodeAudioData should support opus soon, if not already in Canary.

Comment: @RaymondToy @cwilso `MediaRecorder` records in `'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'`. And indeed this bug is being fixed, it is currently fixed in Chrome Canary.