# Web Audio MediaRecorder - How to resample Ogg to 16kHz?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, ogg

I'm trying to get glitch free microphone audio using Web Audio. According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40812061

the only way to do that is with the MediaRecorder API. In Chrome, the only audio format supported in MediaRecorder API is Ogg. When trying to capture microphone input I'm getting ogg audio at 48kHz. Is there any way to resample this down to 16kHz using web audio APIs without introducing any audio glitches?

I'm trying to stream the audio near-realtime so I'm not able to wait to capture it all and process it offline in any sort of batch job.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible way. I haven't actually tried it but it might work.

- Create an offline audio context, `c`, of length 1 and the desired sample rate.
- Grab a chunk (or set of chunks) from the `MediaRecorder`
- Convert the chunk(s) into a `Blob`.
- Convert the `Blob` into an `ArrayBuffer`.
- Call `c.decodeAudioData` with the `ArrayBuffer` that you have.  The output will be the decoded audio data at the desired sample rate.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - I finally got around to trying this, and what I found is that the first packet of Ogg data from the MediaRecorder will resample to 16kHz, but subsequent packets won't. The reason seems to be that decodeAudioData requires the full audio file, which means it won't work for my streaming use case.